# Can I pause a replica on the receiver (subscriber) in postgres12?

Tags: database-replication, postgresql-12

Can I pause a replica on the receiver (subscriber) in postgres12?

just to alter some table structure and then Restart the replica

Comment: if you post the answer I'll vote it as the right answer .. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pause a subscription, [disable it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersubscription.html):

```
alter subscription your_subscription_name disable;
```

To turn it on, just enable it again. It will pick up the transactions that were done in the meantime. As the publisher will keep the necessary WAL segments during that time, you should make sure, the subscription isn't disabled for too long to avoid flooding the file system of the publisher.